# appending values from a look-up table to columns of another data frame based on trailing zero patterns

Tags: r, hash, append, data-cleaning, lookup-tables

Data frame `dat` includes a set of numeric ids in a vector called `code_num`. Some of these ids end with one or more zeros. Others do not. Here are the first three lines:

```
code_num   X1   X2   X3   …   X50
251000     NA   NA   NA       NA        
112020     NA   NA   NA       NA        
537199     NA   NA   NA       NA
```

The full data of `dat` are in the first tab of [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PU4ydUurcxwfcXt-k0WXzkw3zqvduDAG_oCXHDiiBR0/edit?usp=sharing).

Another data frame `lut` includes another set of numeric ids called `code_num_moredetail` that need to be associated with the higher-level identifiers in `dat`. Here are seven example observations of `lut`:

```
code_num_moredetail
251000.99
251743.00
251222.02
112020.01
112029.01
537119.00
537119.99
```

The full data of `lut` are in the second tab of [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PU4ydUurcxwfcXt-k0WXzkw3zqvduDAG_oCXHDiiBR0/edit?usp=sharing).

The trailing zeros in `dat$code_num` are wild card digits. Any value of `lut$code_num_moredetail` that match the numbers preceding the trailing zeros of `dat$code_num` should be considered a matching value, and needs to be added to the ith value of `dat$X1` through `dat$X50` (or beyond - I'm not certain how many matches to expect).

Consider two example cases:

1. if `dat$code_num` = `999000`, then every value of `lut$code_num_moredetail` that matched the pattern `999###.##` would need to be inserted into the columns that begin with the letter X in `dat`.
2. if `dat$code_num` = `999090` then every value of `lut$code_num_moredetail` that matched the pattern `99909#.##` would need to be inserted into the columns that begin with the letter X in `dat`.

Using only the values provided in the example data frames, the final solution would make `dat` look like this:

```
code_num              X1          X2          X3
251000                251000.99   251743.00   251222.02
112020                112020.01   112029.01   NA
537199                537119.00   537119.99   NA
```

I'm seeking an efficient way to augment `dat` with all wild-card-matched values of `lut`.

Note: some values of `dat$code_num` may not match any value of `lut$code_num_moredetail` - a proper solution must accommodate i matches, where i can range from 0 to 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
out <- lut %>%
     mutate(new = substr(code_num_moredetail, 1, 3)) %>% 
     left_join(dat %>%
       transmute(code_num, new = substr(code_num, 1, 3)))  %>% 
    mutate(rn = str_c("X", rowid(new))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = code_num_moredetail) %>%
    select(-new)
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code_num      X1      X2      X3
     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   251000 251001. 251743  251222.
2   112020 112020. 112029.     NA 
3   537199 537119  537120.     NA
```

The digits are in the data.  It is just the tibble print

```
print(out$X3, digits = 10)
[1] 251222.02        NA        NA
```

---

Or may be

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
dat1 <- dat %>%
         transmute(code_num, new = sub("0+$", "", code_num))

lut$new <- str_replace(sub("\\..*", "", sprintf('%.2f', lut[[1]])), 
       paste0(".*(", paste(dat1$new, collapse="|"), ").*"), "\\1")

stringdist_left_join(lut, dat1) %>% 
    select(code_num_moredetail, code_num, new = new.x) %>%
    mutate(rn = str_c("X", rowid(new))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = code_num_moredetail) %>%
    select(-new)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code_num      X1      X2      X3
     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   251000 251001. 251743  251222.
2   112020 112020. 112029.     NA 
3   537199 537119  537120.     NA
```

#### data

```
lut <- structure(list(code_num_moredetail = c(251000.99, 251743, 251222.02, 
112020.01, 112029.01, 537119, 537119.99)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")

dat <- structure(list(code_num = c(251000L, 112020L, 537199L), 
     X1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, NA, NA), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This technically reproduces the desired result for the example set, but always treats the first three values as the non-wild-card digits. Row 2 of `dat` involves 5 digits that are non-wild-cards because there is only one trailing zero at the end of the six-digit integer. I will update my example in the next hour.

Comment: This does an excellent job. I'm encountering an issue I've been stuck on even though your solution fits the question well. In my full data, the `stringdist_left_join()` piped to `select()` induces a cartesian product, where `code_num_moredetail` and `new` match, but `code_num` does not. I added links to the full data frames in my q - what am I missing here? See screenshot of the first few obs for the result of `stringdist_left_join(lut, dat1) %>% select(code_num_moredetail, code_num, new = new.x)` here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1enaiS5XiLWGTpxE5aOdpfkUtS0jiUuE_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @J.Q I think the reason could be because of duplicates in both datasets for the key column.  Here, it was unique for 'dat'

Comment: All values of `dat$code_num` and `lut$code_num_moredetail` are unique - values of `new` are not, which was your goal for linking the `dat$code_num` with `lut$code_num_moredetail` - but I think the variable `new` is behaving differently than I expected. Quite a puzzle...will keep tinkering.

Comment: @J.Q when we do a regex or distance based match, it is a possibility that there could be more matches esp when the 'new' is created based on removal of 0s at the end